# The app has been blocked for your protection

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate

Something is broken on my Windows 10.

Symptoms:

1. I tried to run command prompt with elevated privileges. Rather
   than displaying “do you want to allow the following program to make
   changes to this computer” it shows a message for **unknow publisher**
   i.e. “Do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to
   make changes to your device.”
2. Tried to run *services.msc* &
   *InetMgr.exe*. It says `“the app has been blocked for your protection”`
3. Run the command prompt as administrator and from command line
   executed C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe. At least the IIS started. 
   But when I tried to access the a test web application from browser it says

   > HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found 
   >   The page you are requesting cannot be served because of
   >   the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler.
   >   If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
4. Sometime system hangs and finally crash with blue screen

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows version is either in a very bad shape,
or infected with a very aggressive virus.

I suggest:

- Examine the SMART data for your disk, using a tool such as
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
- If the disk is in good shape, take backups of your data, then format the disk and
  reinstall Windows.